# How to fix '500 Internal Server Error' while file handling?

Tags: php, file-handling

I had made a PHP file using fopen and fwrite and I am trying to execute that file but it's giving me

> Internal Server Error

while making file I had to change the permission to `0775` using `chmod`

```
$book="829310_Revolution_Test_(5)-converted_(4).epub.php";  
$book=str_replace(" ","_",$book);
$path=$book.".php";
$myfile =fopen("../../include/uploaded/epub/$path", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<?php include('hello.php'); ?>";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
chmod("../../include/uploaded/epub/$book", 0775);
chmod("../../include/uploaded/epub/$path", 0775);
```

I want user can execute this file but while trying to execute this file I am getting an Internal Server Error.

Comment: What is the error? what to the logs say?

Comment: no error log has been generated in epub folder

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your file, then check the error-log. A 500 error can come from so many things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: @Qirel still getting same output no change

Comment: Enabling error-reporting will not change the output, but it will ensure the logs are filled with the error. Find your `error.log` file in that folder and see what it contains.

Comment: Partly unrelated, but is your file name: 829310_Revolution_Test_(5)-converted_(4).epub.php.php because you append .php to the end of a string that  ends in .php which if you open a file that doesn't exist, you may get some errors with fopen (I don't remember, but I'm pretty sure it can't auto create)

Answer (score 1):

To know exact errors you should turn on the error reporting by adding following lines at the top of your php file:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

For more info on error reporting, [check this page](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).

Once you get exact error, you can easily debug the server error.

Comment: still getting same output no change

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.